kdb/q xdesc on table, within primary id
I'm trying to get a single line item per id with the largest count, like below:



Primary
Name
Count




1a
AXA
11


1a
FLO
1


1a
FLO
60


1a
AXA
14


2e
AXA
1


2e
ROT
1


2e
ROT
6


2e
ROT
4



tb: ([] Primary:`1a`1a`1a`1a`2e`2e`2e`2e; Name:`AXA`FLO`FLO`AXA`AXA`ROT`ROT`ROT; Count: 11 1 60 14 1 1 6 4)
My first step would be to order the table, descending by count but only within Primary, like this:



Primary
Name
Count




1a
FLO
60


1a
AXA
14


1a
AXA
11


1a
FLO
1


2e
ROT
6


2e
ROT
4


2e
AXA
1


2e
ROT
1



I'm not sure how to do this, I was thinking ````Count xdesc by Primary from tb```, but this gives me an error:
q))a: `Count xdesc by Primary from tb;
'from
  [4]  a: `Count xdesc by Primary from tb;
                                  ^

My ultimate goal is to get one line per Primary id with the highest number of Count:



Primary
Name
Count




1a
FLO
60


2e
ROT
6



I've spent some time on this and I'm not sure where to go from the xdesc step, does anyone know how I can do it better?

Filter-by fby is what you want for this:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby/
q)select from tb where Count=(max;Count) fby Primary
Primary Name Count
------------------
1a      FLO  60
2e      ROT  6

But if the max happens more than once you would get multiple rows:
q)tb,:tb //Duplicate the table in itself
q)select from tb where Count=(max;Count) fby Primary
Primary Name Count
------------------
1a      FLO  60
2e      ROT  6
1a      FLO  60
2e      ROT  6

Nested fby can further resolve this: (i being the virtual index column)
q)select from 
     (select from tb where Count=(max;Count) fby Primary) 
     where i=(first;i) fby Primary
Primary Name Count
------------------
1a      FLO  60
2e      ROT  6

To neaten it up fby can be fed sub-tables for each Primary:
q)select from tb 
       where i=({exec first ind from x where Count=max Count};
               ([]Count;ind:i)) fby Primary
Primary Name Count
------------------
1a      FLO  60
2e      ROT  6

A different method without fby:
q)tb value exec first i where Count=max Count by Primary from tb
Primary Name Count
------------------
1a      FLO  60
2e      ROT  6

Another trick possible is that select by X from Y queries with nothing between select and by will return only the last row per X. So you can sort the table and use this:
q)select by Primary from `Count xasc tb
Primary| Name Count
-------| ----------
1a     | FLO  60
2e     | ROT  6

However note this can only get you the last max row whereas in the above queries you can easily choose between first and last. Also better to avoid sorting the whole table if you don't need to so this query is not suggested as the preferred method.
